# Как сделать первый блок div открытым при загрузке :/

Tags: css3, html5, навигация

Подскажииите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы первый блок был сразу открыт при загрузке страницы :( спасииб

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <title>Мой сайтик</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { 
  margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; padding: 50px }
 .accordion { position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
 
.accordion,.accordion div,.accordion h1,.accordion p,.accordion a,.accordion img,.accordion span,.accordion em,.accordion ul,.accordion li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}

/* Accordion Layout Styles */

.accordion {
 width: 290px;
 padding: 1px 5px 5px 5px;
 background: #141517;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .05);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .05);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .05);

 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.accordion .tab {
 display: block;
 height: 35px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 font: bold 12px/35px Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eee;
 
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .2);

 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;

 background: #6c6e74; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* W3C */

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.accordion .tab:hover,
.accordion div:target .tab {
 color: #2b3b06;
 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .15);

 background: #a5cd4e; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* W3C */

 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .45);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .45);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .45);
}

.accordion div .content {
 display: none;
 margin: 5px 0;
}

.accordion div:target .content {
 display: block;
}

.accordion > div {
 height: 40px;
 overflow: hidden;

 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion > div:target {
 height: 360px;
}

.accordion .content h1 {
 color: white;
 font: 18px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.accordion .content p {
 margin: 10px 0;
 color: white;
 font: 11px/16px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.accordion .content span {
 font: italic 11px/12px Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #4f4f4f;
}

.accordion .content em.bullet {
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 background: #6b8f1a;
 display: inline-block;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion .content ul li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

.accordion .content img {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="accordion">

  <div id="tab-1">
   <a href="#tab-1" class="tab">Обо мне</a>
   <div class="content"><p>Known locally as "SoMa", this neighborhood was home to the dot.com boom and boasts cutting-edge restaurants and boutiques.</p></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="tab-2">
   <a href="#tab-2" class="tab">Мои фото</a>
   <div class="content">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-3.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-2.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3">
   <a href="#tab-3" class="tab">Контакты</a>
   <div class="content">
    <h1>Minsk City</h1>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо скрипт добавить в конец body. Тогда у вас сразу будет выбран нужный элемент.

```
<script>
    window.location.hash="tab-1";
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <title>Мой сайтик</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { 
  margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; padding: 50px }
 .accordion { position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
 
.accordion,.accordion div,.accordion h1,.accordion p,.accordion a,.accordion img,.accordion span,.accordion em,.accordion ul,.accordion li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}

/* Accordion Layout Styles */

.accordion {
 width: 290px;
 padding: 1px 5px 5px 5px;
 background: #141517;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .05);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .05);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .05);

 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.accordion .tab {
 display: block;
 height: 35px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 font: bold 12px/35px Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eee;
 
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .2);

 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;

 background: #6c6e74; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%); /* W3C */

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.accordion .tab:hover,
.accordion div:target .tab {
 color: #2b3b06;
 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .15);

 background: #a5cd4e; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); /* W3C */

 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .45);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .45);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .45);
}

.accordion div .content {
 display: none;
 margin: 5px 0;
}

.accordion div:target .content {
 display: block;
}

.accordion > div {
 height: 40px;
 overflow: hidden;

 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion > div:target {
 height: 360px;
}

.accordion .content h1 {
 color: white;
 font: 18px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.accordion .content p {
 margin: 10px 0;
 color: white;
 font: 11px/16px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.accordion .content span {
 font: italic 11px/12px Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #4f4f4f;
}

.accordion .content em.bullet {
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 background: #6b8f1a;
 display: inline-block;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion .content ul li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

.accordion .content img {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="accordion">

  <div id="tab-1">
   <a href="#tab-1" class="tab">Обо мне</a>
   <div class="content"><p>Known locally as "SoMa", this neighborhood was home to the dot.com boom and boasts cutting-edge restaurants and boutiques.</p></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="tab-2">
   <a href="#tab-2" class="tab">Мои фото</a>
   <div class="content">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-3.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/thumb-2.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3">
   <a href="#tab-3" class="tab">Контакты</a>
   <div class="content">
    <h1>Minsk City</h1>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>
<script>
    window.location.hash="tab-1";
</script>
</html>
```